# How I can get check box value and button value in this stuation? Can any one have suggest

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json-server

I want to get the value of "gender" checkbox and "button" in div rect1,and react 2 to male,female and customer,shop. How I can get it?
I was try to `gender == "male"` or "female" but it return false
What I need change ?

```
function Register() {
  const [username,setUsername]= useState("");
  const [password,setPassword]= useState("");
  const [email,setEmail]= useState("");
  const [phone,setPhone]= useState("");
  const [gender,setGender]= useState("");
  const [role,setRole]= useState("");
  const [error, setError]= useState("");  
  let history = useHistory();
const register = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  axiox.post("http://localhost:5001/api/auth/register", 
  {username,
  email,
  phone,
  password,
  gender,
  role,

    }).then((response)=> {
      console.log("response", response)
      localStorage.setItem("login", JSON.stringify({
     userLogin: true,
      token: response.data.access_token,
      }));
    setError("");
    setUsername("");

    setPassword("");
    setGender(");
    setRole"();
     history.push("/login");
    }).catch(error =>setError(error.response.data.message));
  };
    return (
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value={male} onChange={(e)=> setGender(e.target.value)}/>
        <label for="male"></label>
        <span>Male</span>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value={female} onChange={(e)=> setGender(e.target.value)}/>
        <label for="female"></label>
        <span>Female</span>
    </div>
    <div class="rect1">
      <button class="button" type="button" value={shop} onChange={(e)=> setRole(e.target.value)}><img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/Images/shop 1.png`} /></button>
    </div>
    <div class="rect2">
      <button class="button" type="button" value={customer} onChange={(e)=> setRole(e.target.value)}> <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/Images/take-away.png`} /></button>
```

Thank for helping me

Comment: Please provide codesandbox link. Your code looks erranous starting with the fact that there is no enclosing tags inside return()

Comment: Also you might want to change {male} and {female} to {'male'} and {'female'}

Answer (score 0):

change state to boolean call it  `isMale`

`const [isMale , setIsMale]=useState(false)`

than into return make

```
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value={male} onChange={()=> 
        setGender(true)}/>
        <label for="male"></label>
        <span>Male</span>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value={female} onChange={()=> setGender(false)}/>
        <label for="female"></label>
        <span>Female</span>
```

Comment: Thank u a lot!!!!  That's incredible

Comment: But how about the button here

Comment: what do you mean?